# Telerik : Mark "buttons" in dropdownlist

Tags: html, asp.net, telerik

So I have a problem with marking buttons in a RadToolBarDropDown. Using a simple radbutton then its checked value is changed by the **CheckOnClick="true"** (this also marks the button with its background changing depending on what theme you've chosen) but it doesn't work for the buttons in the dropdown. I have this dropdown list where I have 3 options of what people want to "toggle on/off". So they click on the dropdown, pick one of the options to toggle it off which should then be "marked" in some manner so they know it has been toggled off. I don't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
<telerik:RadToolBarDropDown runat="server" ToolTip="Show/Hide" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon.png">
    <Buttons>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="Walls" Value="TOGGLE_WALLS" />
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="Floor" Value="TOGGLE_FLOOR" />
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="Roof" Value="TOGGLE_CEILING" />
    </Buttons>
</telerik:RadToolBarDropDown>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik support answered me with saying that the buttons in dropdowns does not support a check/toggle function. However, to achieve "the same type of result" you can set the imageURL of the button so whenever a user clicks on it, an image appears:

```
function onDropdownButtonClicking(sender, args) {

    var item = args.get_item();

    if (item.get_imageUrl() === "")
        item.set_imageUrl("../Images/checkmark.png");
    else
        item.set_imageUrl("");
}
```